# Empty value when going from PHP => JSON => JS

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have created a PHP connection to my database and made the following query:

```
$taxRates = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $taxRates[] = $row['mar_tax_rate'];
}
```

I then encoded the result as follows:

```
$jsonobj = json_encode($taxRates, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo "This is jsonobj:<br>" . $jsonobj . "<br>";
```

Which returns:

```
This is jsonobj:
[0,0.35,0.35,0.35,0.35,0.35,0.35,0.35,0.35]
```

The problem that I am having is this.  When I try to echo these results into JS, my result is coming back empty (as far as I can see) -- not an empty array, just nothing. This is how I am trying to feed the result into JS:

```
data:[<?php echo $jsonobj; ?>]
```

Which returns:

```
data:
```

I have tried to alert the PHP variable using

```
alert("<?php echo $jsonobj; ?>");
```

which produces an alert, but is also empty.

Any thoughts?

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/highcharts.2.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/highstock.src.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  drawChart();
});

function drawChart() {

alert("<?php echo join($jsonobj); ?>");
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        type: 'column',
    },      
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },  
    series: [{
        data:[<?php echo $jsonobj; ?>]
    }]
});
};
</script>

</head>

<body>

<button style="height:100px; width:300px;" onclick="drawChart();">Redraw the Chart</button><br />

<div id="chart"></div>

<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('url', 'username', 'password'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
//mysql_close($link);

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('bloch',$link); 
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use Bloch Database : ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query('SELECT mar_tax_rate from bloch.bloch_deficit');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$taxRates = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $taxRates[] = $row['mar_tax_rate'];
}

$jsonobj = json_encode($taxRates, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo "This is jsonobj:<br>" . $jsonobj . "<br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "...made the following query." What follows that isn't a query... Anyways, you can't be showing us all the code. If the second snippet you provided for us works and the third doesn't (while testing them both at the same time), you must be changing something in the `$jsonobj` variable.

Comment: I added the full set of HTML, JS, and PHP.  Same issue.  The alert comes back empty, as does the data:... , even though echoing in PHP shows the array as needed. Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable isn't being defined before you try and put it in to your HTML.  Create the variable with what you need before your HTML in order to get it to the page correctly.

Comment: I was thinking this might be the case, so I did a little research and rearranged things a bit and it's working.  I took all of the PHP out of the <body> and put it in a separate file. I then used <?php include 'filename.php' ?> at the start of the body tag.  This didn't work, so I moved my JS to the bottom of the <body> and everything works great.  Thanks for the advice!  I knew this might be an easy fix, hence my "novice" preface ;)